# Set hostname as a variable in smb.conf file

Tags: linux, samba, smb

I want to enter a variable that represent "netbios name" in smb.conf file. I can set "home dir" as a variable with use %U, what can I use to do same thing to "netbios name"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you type `man 5 smb.conf` you will see a complete list of variables that can be substituted, including `%m`:-

> %m
>       the NetBIOS name of the client machine (very useful).
>
> ```
> This parameter is not available when Samba listens on port 445, as clients no
> longer send this information. If you use this macro in an include statement on a
> domain that has a Samba domain controller be sure to set in the [global] section
> smb ports = 139. This will cause Samba to not listen on port 445 and will permit
> include functionality to function as it did with Samba 2.x.
> ```

Another useful substitution is `$(envvar)`, which allows you to use any exported environment variable in the configuration.